What is the correct syntax to find the row number in a pandas DataFrame for a Date column?
I have a Dataframe that contains a Date column, and some Ticker columns (e.g. 'USDCHF', 'GBPUSD', 'EURUSD'). I want to search the Date column for a given date to find its row number, I then want to update one of the Ticker columns of that row with an integer number.
I can get the column number, but how can I get the row number? There must a be an elegant solution.
I have 1 file to create the Dataframe saved to a .csv file, and another to update this Dataframe after I have re-imported it, as follows:
TestGenMatrix.py:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Date', 'USDCHF', 'GBPUSD', 'EURUSD'])
date = datetime.strptime('2023-01-01', "%Y-%m-%d").date()
x = 0
while x < 20:
    df.loc[x, "Date"] = date
    date = date + timedelta(days=1)
    x += 1
print(df)
df.to_csv('matrix.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)

TestMatrix.py:
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('matrix.csv', parse_dates=True)
date = datetime.strptime('2023-01-10', "%Y-%m-%d").date()
print(df.columns)

col_index = df.columns.tolist().index('GBPUSD')  # Get index of column
#row_index = df[df['Date'] == date].index[0]
#row_index = df.index.get_loc(date)
#row_index = df[df['Date'] == date]
row_index = df['Date'] == date
print(row_index)

df.iloc[row_index, col_index] = 27
# df.loc[row_index, "Date"] = 27
df.to_csv('matrix.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=True)

Everything I have found on this site to find the date seems to generate an error of one form or another.

To understand better - please post sample data and expected output

Please make a [mre]. For specifics see How to make good reproducible pandas examples. It looks like the code doesn't need to be spread across two files when you could just create the df and work on it in the same file.

BTW, you don't need to use the datetime library at all. Use pd.date_range() and pd.Timestamp instead.

Why are you trying to get the row number in the first place? This code works perfectly as far as I can tell. Beware the XY problem. Are you trying to check the result? like print(df.iloc[row_index, col_index])? Why not simply use .loc instead? Or, since this is time-series data, it'd be even easier to set the Date as the index, no?

BTW — and I'll make this the last thing :p — growing a dataframe row-by-row is bad practice. Instead, use pd.date_range() like I mentioned or at least use a list to accumulate the dates, then create the df from that.

gtomer: my first file is the method to reproduce sample data. The expected outcome, as per my OP, is the correct syntax to identify the row number of the desired row.

wjandrea: you are right, I didn't NEED to spread the test over 2 files, but then you would say "why are you doing it like that?" It is a minimal representation of my use case.

The reason I am wanting the row number (as per the OP) is so that I can update a cell in that row. There are probably several ways to do this - mine seemed a good enough way. What is your suggestion?

Thanks for the suggestion to use pd.date_range() - I am  fairly new to Python.

Depending on your definition of an XY Problem, I am asking a specific question, to get a specific answer "How can I identify the row number for a given date?" - is there a problem with that question?

If I were to index the Date column, what would be the syntax to search the index column for the given date to get the row number?

Unfortunately, the suggestion to use 'row_index = df.index[df['Date'] == pd.Timestamp(date)].tolist()' did not work. The result of row_number is [], not the expected result.

@StuartM @-tag people you're replying to, otherwise they don't get a notification. I just happened to be back here and see your comments. I'll reply shortly.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Use .loc to find the row where the date matches.
Use .at to update the specific cell.
df = pd.read_csv('matrix.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
date = datetime.strptime('2023-01-10', "%Y-%m-%d").date()
row_index = df.index[df['Date'] == pd.Timestamp(date)].tolist()
if row_index:
  col_index = df.columns.get_loc('GBPUSD')
  df.at[row_index[0], 'GBPUSD'] = 27
  df.to_csv('matrix.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
else:
  print("Date not found in the DataFrame")

